# Xamarin Update 4.2.13: Debugging starts into an infinite loop on emulator

Tags: xamarin-studio

Using MS VS with Xamarin extension: After updating Xamarin to 4.2.13 the debugger ran into an infinite loop, when deploying.

Answer (score 0):

I had to crash VS and restart it. Cleaned the project and recreated the whole project.

Now it's debugging as before.